# How can I replace lines from one file matched with lines from another file, based on matching pattern, with grep/sed/awk?

Tags: string, text, awk, grep, match

I have two files **nmap.txt** and **hosts.txt**.
The first is, of course, the output from a nmap search, and it looks like this:

```
 ====================================
 192.168.2.1     (ComputerName1)
 Running: Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8
 ====================================
 192.168.2.2     (ComputerName2)
 Running: Running: Linux 3.X
 ====================================
 192.168.2.3     ()
 ====================================
 192.168.2.4     ()
```

It looks like this because the are no DNS entries for the 3rd and 4th computer, and nmap wasn't able to determine 100% their operating systems. But I have the computer names 3 and 4 in the hosts.txt file.

```
192.168.2.3     (ComputerName3)
192.168.2.4     (ComputerName4)
```

What's the easiest way to **replace the missing computer names in nmap.txt** (192.168.2.3 and 192.168.2.4) with their corresponding names in hosts.txt?

I tried **grep -v -F -f nmap.txt hosts.txt > output.txt** which will only output the missing computer names, like this:

```
192.168.2.3     (ComputerName3)
192.168.2.4     (ComputerName4)
```

But that's not what I want.
The output should look like this:

```
====================================
192.168.2.1     (ComputerName1)
Running: Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8
====================================
192.168.2.2     (ComputerName2)
Running: Running: Linux 3.X
====================================
192.168.2.3     (ComputerName3)
====================================
192.168.2.4     (ComputerName4)
```

Maybe something with **while read line**, but I'm not an expert.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in map) && sub(/\(\)$/,""){$0=$0 map[$1]} 1' hosts.txt nmap.txt
====================================
192.168.2.1     (ComputerName1)
Running: Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8
====================================
192.168.2.2     (ComputerName2)
Running: Running: Linux 3.X
====================================
192.168.2.3     (ComputerName3)
====================================
192.168.2.4     (ComputerName4)
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks Ed, I've been trying to find a solution for three days :)

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print ($1 in a?a[$1]:$0)}' hosts nmap
```

Output:

```
====================================
192.168.2.1     (ComputerName1)
Running: Microsoft Windows Vista/7/8
====================================
192.168.2.2     (ComputerName2)
Running: Running: Linux 3.X
====================================
192.168.2.3     (ComputerName3)
====================================
192.168.2.4     (ComputerName4)
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                     # process the hosts file
    a[$1]=$0                  # hash records to a using ip as key
    next
}
{                             # process nmap file
    print ($1 in a?a[$1]:$0)  # print hashed record instead if it exists
}' hosts nmap
```

Comment: Nice approach as long as the formatting between the 2 files is consistent as shown in the sample input, but it'll print the hosts value even if an nmap value was discovered which I'd expect to be undesirable - make the condition in the ternary `($NF=="()") && ($1 in a)` to solve that if you like.

Comment: Thanks James, your solution also works fine for me. As Ed said, it will overwrite the hosts name even if nmap discovers them. But in my case (I forgot to mention), in the hosts file I only have the computers with no DNS entries. So the hosts value discovered by nmap can not be overwritten, as they are missing in the hosts file. Thank you both, guys!

Comment: If the formatting is consistent : awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1' hosts.txt nmap.txt

Comment: @ctac_ that would be less efficient than Jame's current approach since it would require awk to re-split $0 into fields after assignment. Simply printing the desired output is better.